# Type/value mismatch at in template parameter list for class template

Tags: c++, templates, subclass

I have this class:

```
template<typename Bar, template<typename Bar> class Container>
class Foo
{
    Container<Bar> myContainerBar;
};
```

and this subclass:

```
class FooSpecialization : public Foo<std::string,std::vector>
{
};
```

I get the following error at the first line of the second code snippet above (at the subclass):

> type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for
>   ‘template class Container> class Foo’

I also tried

```
class FooSpecialization : public Foo<std::string,std::vector<std::string>>
```

without success. What is wrong? I couldn't find a SO question which addresses this issue.

Comment: `std::vector` has more than one template parameter.

Comment: BTW, `FooSpecialization` is not a specialization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::vector` has more than one template parameter (`Allocator`).

You might solve it this way for example

```
template<typename Bar, template<typename ...> class Container>
class Foo
{
    Container<Bar> myContainerBar;
};


class FooSpecialization : public Foo<std::string, std::vector>
{
};
```